# How can I silence JVM Runtime Error Popup?

Tags: java, jvm, runtime

I'm working on a Java application that consumes methods from a native library (provided by a third party). Eventually, this library fails to handle exceptions properly, causing the application to crash and causing the JVM to show a "Runtime Error NNNNN" popup.

I have a watchdog that expects this application to halt in the event of a crash so it calls the application back up again, but for that, I need it to close completely. However, because of this popup, the watchdog does not act until someone closes the popup (which stays on a server).

Is there any way to completely silence Java, so that in the case of failure, it simply closes the application?

Answer (score 1):

You should run application in headless mode, if you don't want to show any popups. It can be acheived using "`-Djava.awt.headless=true`" in vm argument or you can use at runtime using system property

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

Comment: It didn't work. The only thing it did was to hide the trayicon for the app.
In fact this error message is at a lower level than Java desktop interface. It operates at JVM level, so "java.awt.*" isn't gonna do.